How do I get PowerShell to create a new CSV file?
I'm currently trying to figure out how to get PowerShell to create a new CSV file, and append information to the CSV file it creates. I'm doing this on a test script right now just to try and figure out the functionality, but I'm stuck. Here's what I have currently (For privacy, full file path is reduced to "File Path"):
Clear-Host

$CSVLog = New-Item "\\File Path\Logs\$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss) Test Log.csv" -ItemType File -Force
$i = 0

[PSCustomObject]@{
   'Column1' = ''
   'Column2' = ''
   'Column3' = ''
}

DO
{
  $i++
  $CSVLog.add(
     [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Column 1' = 'Test'
        'Column 2' = 'Super Test'
        'Column 3' = $i
  } ) |
  Export-Csv "\\File Path\Logs\$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss) Test Log.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
} While ($i -lt 5)

Currently, PowerShell just spits out a blank CSV file at the specified location, and will put this in the host window:
Column1 Column2 Column3
------- ------- -------
                       


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> 

What do I need to change here in order to make this work as intended?

Edit (in response to comment):
If you know the names of your columns, just create an empty csv by outputting a single line of the comma separated column names:
'"Column 1","Column 2","Column 3"' > test.csv

Then you can add to it using append:
[PSCustomObject]@{
>>         'Column 1' = 'Test'
>>         'Column 2' = 'Super Test'
>>         'Column 3' = 1
>>   } | export-csv -path test.csv -NoTypeInformation -append

Original answer:
You don't need to append each item one at a time, just output the objects onto the pipeline into Export-Csv and it will take care of appending for you:
1..5 | %{[PSCustomObject]@{
         'Column 1' = 'Test'
         'Column 2' = 'Super Test'
         'Column 3' = $_
   } } | export-csv -path test.csv -NoTypeInformation

once you've added some initial values, you can use -append to add more:
6..9 | %{[PSCustomObject]@{
         'Column 1' = 'Test'
         'Column 2' = 'Super Test'
         'Column 3' = $_
   } } | export-csv -path test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append

or

This isn't working, nor is this what I'm looking for. I'm looking to create a blank csv, then add values via a loop. I don't want hardcoded values.

@RustyAndroid see my update
